# WEBScraping in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

guys i have to take the lottery results from a website page ..... thru a webservice and display it on web client.

so far i got to extract z result usin the code :

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://www.loterienationale.mu/loto/tirages-et-archives") as HttpWebRequest;
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        webRequest.GetResponse().Close();

        MatchCollection m1 = Regex.Matches(responseData, @"(?<=<span class=""text-resultat-num""[^>]*>).*?(?=</span>)", RegexOptions.Singleline);

        foreach (Match m in m1)
        {
            Response.Write(m.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

BUT i do not want it to WRITE. Instead i want it to return the value to the client.

HOW CAN I DO IT???

help please.

Comment: Parsing HTML with Regex... *cool*.. \*cough\*cough\* But, umm... you want to return the value; so place a `label` on the form and set its `Text` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML Agility pack or some other tool. Regex is probably not the best candidate for what you are trying to do.As Andrew suggested, use a Label control and assign the value to the Text property of the control.

Comment: thnxx guys .. im going to try z Agility pack _^^